# Do I need a where clause in a conditional UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We imported a lot of data from another table. Now I'm trying to correct some of them.

```
UPDATE [x10ddata].[dbo].[ResourceTest]
  SET [Country] = (CASE
      WHEN [Country] IN ('Aezerbaijan', 'AZERBIJAN') THEN 'Azerbaijan'
      WHEN [Country] = 'Belgique'    THEN 'Belgium'
      WHEN [Country] = 'China (RPC)' THEN 'China'
      WHEN [Country] = 'Columbia'    THEN 'Colombia'
     WHEN [Country] = 'Croatia (Local Name: Hrvatska)' THEN 'Croatia'
     .....//...
     WHEN [Country] IN ('U.S.', 'U.S.A', 'U.S.A.', 'US', 'USA', 
                         'USA - Maryland', 'USAQ') THEN 'United States'
    END)   
  GO
```

I didn't use **ELSE** because many rows have valid country. My question is to know whether I need to the **WHERE** clause to filter the rows that will be affected?

The reason I'm asking this question is that, I've selected into a test table and tried the the script. According to the output, all the rows affected, but when I check closely, not all the rows were affected. It's confusing.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you want to run the correction code over all rows then no.

Comment: For any record where the `CASE` statement does not hit one of the specified conditions, `NULL` is what the `CASE` returns, so the Country is being set to `NULL` in these cases.

Comment: What are the rows that "have a valid country" now set to? `NULL`? Simply include `ELSE [Country]` as quick inefficient work around.

Comment: If you can properly normalize your data you don't even need this update at all. Storing the country name in a table this is a pretty good indication that normalization would be more appropriate here instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` statement will return `null` if none of the `when` clauses are met.  You can verify this with this simple sql:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 2
select case when @i = 1 then 'A' end AS Column1
```

This will return `null` since `@i` is not `1`.

To fix this in your case, you can either add the `where` clause like you said, or the simpler option might be to add `ELSE [Country]` after all of your `WHEN` clauses.  This would mean "If I don't need to change the country field, then just use the same value that was there before."

Answer (score 2):

You won't need a WHERE clause, but the ELSE clause is needed. Change your statement to:

```
UPDATE [x10ddata].[dbo].[ResourceTest]
  SET [Country] = (CASE
      WHEN [Country] IN ('Aezerbaijan', 'AZERBIJAN') THEN 'Azerbaijan'
      WHEN [Country] = 'Belgique'    THEN 'Belgium'
      WHEN [Country] = 'China (RPC)' THEN 'China'
      WHEN [Country] = 'Columbia'    THEN 'Colombia'
     WHEN [Country] = 'Croatia (Local Name: Hrvatska)' THEN 'Croatia'
     .....//...
     WHEN [Country] IN ('U.S.', 'U.S.A', 'U.S.A.', 'US', 'USA', 
                         'USA - Maryland', 'USAQ') THEN 'United States'
     ELSE [Country]
    END)
```

Comment: while this works it seems wrong to update rows to the same value.

Comment: @Jodrell - the alternative is to leave off the ELSE clause, in which case all rows which don't match any of the country names in the WHEN clauses would have their [Country] column set to NULL. Another alternative is to add a WHERE clause which re-states the country names, but this is increases the possibility of errors if a country name is missed, typed incorrectly, etc. I think that the use of a CASE expression without a WHERE clause is a reasonable alternative. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively,

Make a conversion table,

```
DECLARE @conversion TABLE
(
    [Before] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    [After] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @conversion
VALUES
('Aezerbaijan', 'Azerbaijan'),
...
('USAQ', 'United States');
```

Then do,

```
UPDATE [x10ddata].[dbo].[ResourceTest]
            SET [Country] = [C].[After]
    FROM
            [x10ddata].[dbo].[ResourceTest]
        JOIN
            @conversion [C]
                ON [C].[Before] = [C].[Country];
```

This has a number of potential performance benefits over the extend `CASE` approach, among which is only effecting rows that need to change.

Its probably worth using a temporary table instead of a table variable and creating an index on [Before] to optimize the join.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need a where clause because your CASE statements contain your logic.

**Note:** If a value doesn't match any of your CASE statements then it will return null. So I recommend adding ELSE [Country] at the end. Here's an example that demonstrates what I'm saying

```
SELECT * INTO #yourTable
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 ID, CAST('OldValue' AS VARCHAR(25)) val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 , 'OldValue'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'Doesnt need to be updated'
) A

SELECT *
FROM #yourTable;
```

Results:

```
ID          val
----------- -------------------------
1           OldValue
2           OldValue
3           Doesnt need to be updated
```

Now update:

```
UPDATE #yourTable
SET val = 
    CASE 
        WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'NewValue1'
        WHEN ID = 2 THEN 'NewValue2'
        --Add this so you leave values alone if they don't match your case statements
        ELSE val
    END
FROM #yourTable


SELECT *
FROM #yourTable
```

Results:

```
ID          val
----------- -------------------------
1           NewValue1
2           NewValue2
3           Doesnt need to be updated
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't NEED it. Aside from the performance cost that may be incurred through additional (unnecessary) writes to disk and locking (blocking other sessions), the physical outcome would be the same.

One could argue that you SHOULD use a WHERE clause, not only for performance reasons, but to better capture and convey intentions.